# Why does "this.$refs.inputField.focus()" not work?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created an input field and given it a `ref="inputField"` like so:

```js
<input ref="inputField">
<button @click="btn">Click</button>
```

On click I want to add focus to it and I have written the code like this:

```js
<script>
methods: {
  btn() {
    this.$refs.inputField.focus()
  }
}
</script>
```

But this does not work.

How to make an input on focus when the button is clicked?

Comment: Your code works as written.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works.
[See this example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdD5cbiBleHBvcnQgZGVmYXVsdCB7XG4gICAgbWV0aG9kczoge1xuICAgICAgYnRuKCkge1xuICAgICAgICB0aGlzLiRyZWZzLmlucHV0RmllbGQuZm9jdXMoKVxuICAgICAgfVxuICAgIH1cbiAgfVxuPC9zY3JpcHQ+XG5cbjx0ZW1wbGF0ZT5cbiAgPGlucHV0IHJlZj1cImlucHV0RmllbGRcIj5cbiAgPGJ1dHRvbiBAY2xpY2s9XCJidG5cIj5DbGljazwvYnV0dG9uPlxuPC90ZW1wbGF0ZT4iLCJpbXBvcnQtbWFwLmpzb24iOiJ7XG4gIFwiaW1wb3J0c1wiOiB7XG4gICAgXCJ2dWVcIjogXCJodHRwczovL3NmYy52dWVqcy5vcmcvdnVlLnJ1bnRpbWUuZXNtLWJyb3dzZXIuanNcIlxuICB9XG59In0=).

You do at least need `export default` though:

```js
<script>
 export default {
    methods: {
      btn() {
        this.$refs.inputField.focus()
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I get this "Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'unknown'.Vetur(2339)" and input field is not focused

Comment: Does your code work? Then it might just be an IDE issue with Vetur.

Comment: any ideas on how to fix that?